# Android List View Search Query's

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-listview

I'm building an application that displays Job Search query's. And I am trying to save them to a database.

I found a layout for Android apps that displays scrollable items to a list - 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

How would I be able to retrieve data from a site, and display the results on to the list of my android app?The application is going to be displaying Ad's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>  

    package de.vogella.android.listactivity;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
        // use your custom layout
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
```

How would I be able to retrieve data off another website and intergrate it into my app display it within the list?

Comment: show us your attempt..

Comment: Sorry, I was putting up the code.

Comment: I think your question is too broad. You are not even trying to display ads, but vogellas tutorial. Please try to narrow down your question.

Comment: Yeah, well i put that example up because it was minimalistic. I'm just looking for examples on how to get data off a site and display the results within a list. Is there ways to retrieve data within a android app off of websites? Say like a stock stats website or weather information?

Comment: Does anyone have a better example of this? I found a thread on Stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076789/how-to-display-the-database-in-a-listview-android?rq=1

Creating a database and displaying the results within a list in my app.